# Twilio put ongoing subaccount caller into conference with master account

Tags: twilio

Call flow looks like.

1. Sub-account verified number generates a call to voice recording
2. Digits are gathered
3. Option 2 connects back to the number where the call looks like it was coming from (for the reason that incoming calls from the same number sometimes drop you into voicemail, I can't simply dial back the originator, it works but not ALWAYS it depends on the carrier, also then it looks like the call is coming from themselves which is weird but less important).

What I know I can do.

1. Use a 2nd twilio # or verified # on that sub account to dial().conference() and drop both parties into that conference. Great but I don't want to have to update all my subaccounts every time I want to make a change to something there and I'd like to be able to tell the sub accounts exactly where to expect calls from so they know to answer, even with caller id it's not always 100% depending on the phone and/or phone system some of them have office sips.
2. What I'd like to do is generate the 2nd call (back to the originating number) from a master account controlled #. Problem being I'm already in call with the first party that was generated by the sub account. I don't want to hang up on them. So either I need to be able to dial a number verified or purchased on my master account from all my sub accounts OR I need to be able to transfer an ongoing call into a master account conference.

Other ideas appreciated. Not a twilio noob so feel free to be brief and I'll do the work of posting back code example for the benefit of others.

Comment: Did you ever work out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned myself that [subaccounts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts) do not have access to main accounts numbers.

Thus the [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) scenario you describe is a good workaround.

> Use a 2nd twilio # or verified # on that sub account to
>   dial().conference() and drop both parties into that conference. Great
>   but I don't want to have to update all my subaccounts every time I
>   want to make a change to something there and I'd like to be able to
>   tell the sub accounts exactly where to expect calls from so they know
>   to answer, even with caller id it's not always 100% depending on the
>   phone and/or phone system some of them have office sips.